# Identificar itens de uma combobox e jogar no laço for utilizando Selenium JS e Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, navegador-de-internet, selenium-webdriver

Preciso fazer um laço for para abrir um número x de abas e cada aba utilizar uma "dashboard" diferente. A primeira parte eu já fiz como poderia fazer a segunda? Lembrando preferencialmente com Xpath utlizando JS e Python. Aqui está o codigo:

```js
# Abre qnt de abas de acordo com os dashboards
for i in range(0, len(config['idDashboard'])):
 browser.execute_script('window.open("' +  config['url'] + ' ", "_blank");')
 time.sleep(2)
```

```js
# Configura um dashboard por aba 
for i in range(0, len(config['idDashboard'])):
 time.sleep(10)
 browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[i])
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```